# Count number of unique days using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
            h1 h2         date  c
0   002599f58e  A   2019-09-23  1
1   002599f58e  A   2019-09-24  3
2   005344fe83  C   2019-09-30  7
3   005344fe83  D   2019-10-02  1
4   005344fe83  D   2019-10-03  2
```

I would like to count the number of *unique days* `h1` is in `h2`. So, I should end up with something like:

```
            h1  h2  count
0   002599f58e   A      2
2   005344fe83   C      1
4   005344fe83   D      2
```

Because A appears in two different days, C in one, and D in two other days. I've tried something like

```
days = df.groupby(["h1", 
                   df["date"].dt.floor("D"),
                   "h3"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
#convert to datetimes and if necessary remove times by floor
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.floor("D")

days = df.groupby(["h1", 'h2'])["date"].nunique().reset_index(name="count")
print (days)
           h1 h2  count
0  002599f58e  A      2
1  005344fe83  C      1
2  005344fe83  D      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
days = df[['h1', 'h2', 'date']].drop_duplicates().groupby(['h1', 'h2']).count().reset_index()
```